# Getting CSS of an element using C#

Tags: c#, html, css

In javascript I can easily use JQuery to get css, for example:

```
$("#id").css();
```

I need to do the same in c#. Im getting the html source into string (usually parsing it with agility pack), and I need to get the css values of a specific htmlnode.

does a way doing so exist?

thanks.

Comment: possibly NO... you can only get the values in the attrubutes in the html element, but possibly you can't get the css values from a css class from server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for-->[HTML Element Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx) and [HTML Element GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute.aspx).

Although, I do suggest to use jquery as much as possible for this. HTML is more for UI, and C# code is usually more for business logic, so if you can avoid mixing this as much as possible, that is better :)

Comment: Wow, genuinely surprised that even this exists.

Comment: yes Im trying to get whatever I can through jquery but this one I need to get using c#. anyway your suggestion looks promising, I'll look into it and update if it did the trick. thanks for your reply.

Comment: seems ok, but working with the controller is really annoying.. thanks for the solution.